# Delphi Quick Report printing conditions on back of a page

Tags: delphi, quickreports

I need to print conditions on the back of a report if the printer supports duplex printing. I get this right by creating a child band depending if the default printer has duplex printing capabilities.

The problem occurs when the user selects a different printer in the preview where the duplex printing differs from the default printer. How can I suppress or create this band after the user has clicked on the Print Button

Comment: Have you tried the quickreport customer support? They're usually very good with this stuff.

Comment: If I remember correctly you have the OnBeforePrint event for each band.

Comment: Hi Gerhard, can you explain me how you solved this with the child band? I am facing the same issue but for some reason, the printed back is always empty...

Comment: I have with previous issues tried Quick Reports Customer Support but without any response.
The before method gets called on preview taking the default printers duplex capabilities.
I have a Summary Band on the first page and create a child band for this if the printer has duplex capabilities